# Grafana panel query only pick up one value when using query variables from Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I have defined a query variable like
[image]

When using this variable to build a panel query
[image]

I tried to investigate the problem via query inspector, then I found that the query only pick up one value from the variable with the query string of "sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{node=~"de1tst-78j9w-infra-46r7f"})"
[image]

And because the host that the query picks up coincidentally doesn't contain the metric, so it shows "N/A".

I want the panel query collects all nodes metrics that the variable returns, how could I let the panel query as expected by specifying "node=~${workers}"?

Comment: The query returns multiple values for your variable, as you can see under "Preview of values". By default, the first one is selected. If you want another one or multiple, you have to select them from the drop down (for multiple turn on the "Multi value" option).

Comment: Even if I turn on the "multi-value" option, nevertheless the query string still picks up only one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dashboard settings > Variables, set the following:

```
Hide               = empty
Multi-value        = enable
Include All option = enable
```

Use the "workers" picklist selector which will appear at the top of the dashboard to select the desired nodes or the "All" option.

Comment: Nice! I can use the "All" option to select all nodes that are filtered out by the query variable now.
In addition,  without selecting all nodes by choosing node names or all from the dashboard label, is there another workaround that always select nodes from the query variable?